# SQL Query to get list of services in one program if the client is also in another program

Tags: sql

I am looking to pull a list of medical services for clients that are in two programs. What I need is, if the client is in Wraparound program, I need to pull a list of services they've received in the MH program for a specified date range.

Comment: Please provide your table structure, what you have tried and your database system.

Comment: @PaulBrainard you should put your code in the question, not in comments

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cv.client_id,
cv.clientvisit_id,
Programs.program_desc,
Clients.text1 As Client,
cv.visittype,
cv.duration,
cv.non_billable,
cv.timein as event_date,
Employees.last_name
FROM clientvisit cv
Inner Join programs On programs.program_id = cv.program_id
Inner Join Clients On Clients.client_id = cv.client_id
Inner Join Employees On Employees.emp_id = cv.emp_id
WHERE programs.program_desc = 'MH' AND (SELECT cv.client_id from 
clientvisit WHERE programs.program_desc = 'Wraparound') AND
(cv.timein >= @param1 AND cv.timein <= @param2)
```

Comment: The error I'm getting is Invalid Custom SQL query. An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.

Answer (score 0):

Putting part of the question as an answer is really confusing, but the problem you're having is this bit:

```
AND (SELECT cv.client_id from 
    clientvisit WHERE programs.program_desc = 'Wraparound') AND
```

The sub-select is return an id of some kind, but you're trying to do an `AND` against it.

I'm guessing you mean to compare that id against something, so something like

```
AND (SELECT cv.client_id from 
    clientvisit WHERE programs.program_desc = 'Wraparound') = {id you want to compare to} AND
```